# "Ambiguous call to overloaded function" with enum classes in MSVC compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I was trying to do template specialization with values, one incarnation being bool, while the other being enum class. I was fighting with the compiler for a day, but did not manage to overcome the "Ambiguous call to overloaded function" error.
That code is ugly and rather long, but here is a simple test case:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Foo { Bar };
enum class Waldo { Fred };

template<Foo ARG, typename... _Types>
inline bool DOIT( _Types&&... _Args )
{
    return true;
}

template<Waldo ARG, typename... _Types>
inline bool DOIT( _Types&&... _Args )
{
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << DOIT<Foo::Bar>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << DOIT<Waldo::Fred>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Both clang 3.8 and gcc 4.8.3 compiles this without a hitch, with the standard being set to c++11, but MSVC keeps firing me the C2668 error message.

AFAIK one reason for enum class was to avoid implicit conversion, but don't know for sure. Is this a compiler error, or some deficiency in the standard?

Comment: Considering your use of a scoped enum, definitely a MSVC hiccup.

Comment: The clang compiler built into Visual Studio says *"error : definition with same mangled name as another definition"*. Reminds me of an old VC++ bug where they mangled the name with the function parameter types, and not with the template types. Perhaps this problem is still alive?

Answer (score 5):

Technically the code you posted is an ill-formed program no diagnostic required because you used an identifier starting with an `_` followed by an upper case letter.  Such identifiers are reserved by the standard for your compiler's implementors.

But that isn't your problem.

---

I have seen one case ever where MSVC got it right while **both** gcc and clang got it wrong when following the standard.

On top of that, the ambiguity makes no sense here.

Your compiler is busted.

A way that should work is:

```
template<Foo ARG, typename... Ts>
inline bool DOIT( std::integral_constant<Foo, ARG>, Ts&&... args )
{
  return true;
}
template<Waldo ARG, typename... Ts>
inline bool DOIT( std::integral_constant<Waldo, ARG>, Ts&&... args )
{
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << DOIT(std::integral_constant<Foo, Foo::Bar>{}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << DOIT(std::integral_constant<Waldo, Waldo::Fred>{}) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which [works on this online MSVC compiler](http://rextester.com/AMTE88249).